# Can't see a button in designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm on Windows 10, maintaining a C# Desktop application using Visual Studio 2019, putting controls onto a Form (System.Windows.Forms.Form). I'm attempting to change an application; reworking where the controls go etc., so there is code and control design that I want to keep and put into different locations. I am using the visual designer and connecting to code using the control events (as opposed to creating the forms dynamically).

I have Document Outline visible on the left; I cut several groups of controls I intend to paste back later, so all that one particular TableLayoutPanel has in it now is two buttons.  But I cannot find those buttons in the designer. I can see them in the Document Outline; they're in a TableLayoutPanel (in a group box in another TableLayoutPanel on a TabPage, etc.). When I click on a control in the Document Outline, the corresponding control is usually highlighted in the View; however, when I click on either of these buttons, nothing is highlighted in the view.

I tried resizing the Form (which determines the sizes of all these panels/tableLayoutPanels set to 'fill'); it's currently at 1367,850; one of the button locations shows as 664,752, but I don't know in what coordinate system that applies. I tried manually setting the location to 50,50 in the properties window, but it won't let me change that there.

These buttons appear at the bottom of the form; they've never appeared there, but I've noticed sometimes the designer has shown dotted-line outlines of them outside the form entirely. They appear in place when the application is run.

I've tried changing between the 100% scaling and the 125% scaling; that didn't help. For two buttons, I suppose I could delete them and recreate them, but there are many, many controls on this UI, and if there's some trick to making things appear I'd like to know about it.

Is there a trick to this that I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks, but these are not showing up in the component tray, and I see no exception. They're displaying and working fine in the applicaiton. I think they were created on a bigger display, and might appear there. There should be some way to see them and move them on a smaller display, though.

Comment: Can you find them in the controls dropdownlist in the properties pane?

Comment: Yes. I've found that I can see them on a higher-resolution display also.